# Eval code in node's global scope from within a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, eval

General: In node.js, how does one access the scope of the file being executed?

Example: I have a module (mod.js) and a file that requires it (main.js). From within mod.js I need to do an eval() with access to the scope of main.js, as follows:

mod.js:

```
exports.runCode = function(code) {
  var x = 1;
  // do some stuff to x and code
  return eval(code) + x;
}
```

main.js:

```
var amod = require('./mod');

var func = function(a,b) {
  return a + b;
}

console.log(amod.runCode('2+2'));    // works fine
console.log(amod.runCode('func()')); // ReferenceError: func is not defined
```

bash:

```
$ node main
```

Thus far, I have tried using node's global, vm, and process objects, as well as various closures

Note also that I only have control over mod.js, not main.js (and yes, I am aware of the security implications)

Comment: Just change mod.js to `exports.runCode = eval`

Comment: This is a minimal example. -- there are other parts of the runCode() function (I've now updated the above code to show this)

Comment: Then yeah, it's not possible to access main.js's scope from mod.js, the best you could do is `amod.runCode('func = ' + func + '; func(1, 2)')` or just `global.func = func` inside main.js.

Comment: If your code is no more complex than your example then you could simply stringify the function and it will work. ``console.log(amod.runCode(`(${func.toString()})(2, 2)`));`` Otherwise, not accessible. I also missed your note `I only have control over mod.js` :)

Comment: it is arbitrarily complex

Answer (score 1):

Based on feedback from rednoyz, I realized that the scope of execution would be the function "define" and not the module.  So here's a new version of define that fixes it.

```
exports.define = function(__code) {
   eval.call(module, __code);
}
```

I also tested to avoid the few errors I made in the last post.

```
var amod = require('./mod');

amod.define("var f=function(a,b) {return a + b;}");
amod.define("var g=function(a,b) {return a*b;}");

console.log(amod.runCode('2+2'));    // works fine - 5
console.log(amod.runCode('f(2,3)')); // works fine - 6
console.log(amod.runCode('g(3,4)')); // works fine - 13
```

Comment: Don't use `eval.call`. It accomplishes nothing.

Comment: Again, this would be ok if I was in control of main.js. The idea is that main.js is written by a user of mod.js, writing whatever arbitrary functions they want, then calling the single runCode() function on a long string of text which may, or may not, include function calls.

Comment: Still not ideal, but perhaps better would be to to allow users to write generic functions, then pass them into mod.js: function f(){...} amod.addToScope(f); Would need to test if this actually works...

Comment: Seems to do this I would need a way of calling eval for a specific context (eval.call(...) does not work, as Bergi points out)

Comment: Dear rednyz, could you paste your code, please?   I actually tested everything pasted in the 2nd post including eval.call but maybe I missed something.

Comment: Okay, I see that eval.call(module, ...) actually creates the code in the global scope and not the module scope.  Hope you are able to make your addToScope() work, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you'd have to define functions that you want to use in the module in the module itself, you could probably write a new function to inject these into the module's scope,

```
exports.define = function(__code) {
   eval(__code);
}
```

Using the new define interface

```
amod.define('func = function(a,b) {
  return a + b;
}');
```

There are other patterns you could use as well like defining all functions definitions as an object and passing that to the module to get access to, or you could use the global scope as suggested by @idbehold

Do share with us if you hack a way into sharing scopes across two modules.

Comment: actually it seems to work if i leave off the 'var' and just say 'func=function(){...}', but it doesn't really help because I may have functions defined this way: function func() {...}